# Extracting data from HTML table with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to extract the data from the table on the following website. I.e Club, venue, start time. http://www.national-autograss.co.uk/february.htm

I have got many examples on here working that use a css class table but this website doesn't. I have made an attempt with the code below but it doesn't seem to provide any output. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.national-autograss.co.uk/february.htm").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements elements = doc.select("table#table1"); 
        String name;


        for( Element element : elements ) 
        {
            name = element.text(); 
            System.out.println(name);
        }
}
```

}

Comment: An id should be unique, so you should use directly `doc.select("#table1")` and so on

Comment: Didac you should post your answer so Harg can check it and mark the thread as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An id should be unique, so you should use directly `doc.select("#table1")` and so on